# icacls fails to provide access to file but the message says it is successfully completed

Tags: batch-file, powershell, command-line, acl, icacls

I am trying to assign a windows group to a particular file.

```
icacls "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\MyProj\Logger.exe" /grant "My System Administrators":(OI)(CI)F
```

The result is as follows

> "processed file: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyOrg\MyProj\Logger.exe
>   Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

but when i open the properties of the file and view it in security tab , the group is not listed.

Am i missing anything ? Or any other way is there to provide access to a file?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from following question. His question is similar to my question.

https://superuser.com/questions/628930/windows-7-command-line-add-group-users-to-file